# Pulling a feature branch into my other feature branch

Tags: git

I checked out my branch where I want to pull another branch and I did git merge but I received that it does not point to a commit and requires a single revision.

```
git checkout feature/branch1
git merge feature/branch2     # Does not point to a commit
git rebase feature/branch2    # Needed a single revision
```

I also tried git pull but recieved:

```
git pull feature/branch2      # Does not appear to be a git repository
```

How should I copy data from feature/branch2 to feature/branch1?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "_Does not point to a commit_"? What is the exact output?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `git pull origin feature/branch2`. Replace origin with whatever you've named the remote repository.

The command works like this:

`git pull [remote name] [branch name]`

Which explains why you're getting the error message "Does not appear to be a git repository."